# Programatically create views and overlap a view by inflating from xml to created two or more views

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have created above screen programatically and now I want add View as shown in below figure
[image]

How can I add views as shown in above figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create views by inflating xml and then ad it to this layout whenever required

Comment: I have created view and inflated it but how to add as shown in above image?